# Error when importing DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, decision-tree

When I try to import a DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn.tree I receive the following attribute error: `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'`

My code is:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

Output:

```
0.23.2

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

Comment: Sklearn 0.23.2 is roughly 4 years old. Have you tried upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: and if for some reason you must use this older sklearn, you probably need to also install an older numpy

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using np.float as a data type, which is no longer supported by NumPy. As the error message suggests, you should replace **np.float** with float or **np.float64** in your code.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.2, 3.4, 5.6], dtype=float) # use float instead of 
np.float
```

Please try this and five an update.